# Checkbox in TemplateField ItemTmplate event won't fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

Ok I am using a column with check box to be able to select my data row from a GridView. But The OnCheckChanged event won't fire. I have tried reading articles to make it work and copy code exactly and it just won't fire. I am using vb.net and asp.net

```
        <asp:GridView ID="locationDetailGrid" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="locationSelection" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Protected Sub CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim checkbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(checkbox.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Response.Write(row.Cells(0).Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you're databinding the GridView also on postbacks. Add an `If Not Page.IsPostback` into Page_Load around your databinding stuff of the GridView.

If you rebind the GridView on postbacks, you're preventing events from triggering.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGridToDataSourceAndDataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something simple I just couldn't figure out what

Comment: You are right, I also think so. Just now I tested. It is working after checking postback data bind to gridview.